# PDF Google Doc Viewer

Tags: pdf, seo, indexing

I use google doc to show embedded PDF on my site. It uses iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emathhelp.net%2Fpdf%2F1%2F1331155133.pdf&embedded=true" width="800" height="500" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

I wonder how Google will index content of PDF?
Will in Google search appear site with embedded PDF or direct PDF link? And how this will affect my ranking?

I want the page, not direct PDF link to appear in search results. If above method does not work, is there some turnaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to leverage your ranking for some specific texts (keywords) that are inside your pdf files and you want to prevent it from being indexed and make it invisible, the answer is pretty clear:  you can not or Google do not allow you to do this.

as a solution, i suggest you to put your pdf files in a path and mark the path as disallow in your robots.txt file.
Then you should use something like a database and write some codes (based on what platform you use) to get your pdf texts while you are uploading your pdf file. then use something like this viewer :
http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html
 when the page with specific pdf loads, your application will put grabbed texts from database and puts it inside a noscript tag. remember to optimize your page's meta tags based on your pdf file

Comment: I want to show pdf as embeded without direct accessing it, so people can see advertisments. Is there any way to do it? Maybe some redirections, .htaccess or other stuff?

Comment: check this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498491/how-do-i-tell-search-engines-not-to-index-content-via-secondary-domain-names) put your pdf files in a directory and prevent indexing the folder that your files are inside then use method i mentioned above. actually, in this method, you hide the pdf files then you create a linkage between each pdf files and pages that contain the pdf.